# Need JQuery to select a table only if its 1st row has more than 1 column

Tags: jquery, selector, tablesorter

I need to select and act on a table element with JQuery, but only when it contains at least one row with more than one column. The following selector works, but only gets me part way:

```
$('#my_table_is:has(tbody tr)').doSomething();
```

Variations I have tried with no success are:

```
$('#my_table_id:has(tbody > tr > td:eq(1))').doSomething();
$('#my_table_id:has(tbody tr:nth-child(1))').doSomething();
$('#my_table_id:has(td:eq(1))').doSomething();
```

What combination of selector and filter will make this work?

BTW, the reason I need this is that tablesorter with a multi-column sortList, will apparently blow up when there is only 1 column in the table output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just a good ole check?

```
if (1 < $('#tbl thead th').size()) ...
```

Comment: @neouser99 Thanks, that did the trick.  FWIW, I needed a row within the tbody, so my solution was:
    if (1 < $('#tbl_id tbody tr td').size()) {...

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to actually **fix** the tablesorter instead of *hacking around*? (I assume you mean http://tablesorter.com/).

Comment: The other issue with tablesorter is its recognition of the column datatype by the first row only.

Comment: I'm pretty happy with tablesorter so far.  It def. beats returning to the DB and writing dynamic SQL to change an ORDER BY.  And I prefer not to hack up someone else's library because I don't want to re-hack it whenever he/she releases a new version

Comment: Good point, even though I am sure the author would be happy to incorporate your fix.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with the following selector (also for an old version of TableSorter):

`#tableID:has( tbody > tr > td + td )`

The idea is that it will find the table only if it has a `tbody` with a `tr` that has at least two sibling `td` in it.